# "Vote too old to be changed" defect

Tags: bug, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defect in “vote too old to be changed” check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29171/defect-in-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-check)

I upvoted an answer, then cancelled it.  Then later on after it was augmented/improved I tried to upvote again and was told I could not.

This is a defect I think.

There are lots of similar questions here on Meta, but there are too many for me to determine if ths is a dupe - because this is a special case and it is unclear to me if it is desired behavior or not.

IMO this is brain dead.

Comment: "By Design" according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29171/defect-in-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-check

Comment: It's definitely a defect. The users' model of the system is completely different from how the system behaves, and it's not like this is a fundamental thing (or at least I wouldn't expect it to be), so it should be solved by changing the system's behaviour rather than telling users that they're wrong every time. It's a big failing on anticipating how the users will form their mental models of how rolling back votes works.

Comment: Too many to determine if something is a dupe...? Did you see the many "[closed]" in the titles? (And may I ask if you even read one?)

Comment: It's a duplicate many times over... Unfortunately, this has been discussed to death and every time the response is "status-wontfix".

Comment: You're supposed to be able to vote again if it got edited, so I'm not sure what augmented/improved means in this case.

Comment: "later on after it was augmented/improved" you can change your vote after a post is edited, so this doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: Hmm,  Perhaps it was a comment that added more information and not the actual answer itself.  I have to go back and check.  And yes, I did read some of them.  In that case perhaps this is as-designed.